# Manage roles in asp.net website menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I want to know if it's possible to configure roles in te website menu to prevent to see some aspx, also if get the current role in the c# (code behind) once the user was loggedIn. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using asp.net roles provider and asp.net menu control, you can use the web.sitemap file to control the menu links display based on roles as below.

```
<siteMapNode url="/Test/Default.aspx" roles="Admin" title="Test" description="">
```

Otherwise you can use a loginview control to display different links based on roles as below.

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
       Menu Link1
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Menu Link2
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

If you are not using role providers and say store that information in the session or somewhere, you can use something similar in the aspx file.

```
<% if (Session["admin"].ToString() == "Admin") { %>
  Link1
<% } else { %>
  Link2
<%} %>
```

You can get the current roles for the logged in user as

```
string[] roleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```